# Where is stored the output of Log in android apps?

Tags: android, logging

I'm trying to get acquainted with logging for android.

So I added

```
Log.d("hey there!");
```

to my app.

When the app finishes, how do I analyze its logs? Where are the files located etc?

Comment: here: [aLogcat on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd).

Comment: yeah, that looks like what I want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're Android device is connected to Eclipse then you can view your logs in real time by opening LogCat:

Window -> Show View -> Other... -> LogCat

To view your logs over a WiFi connection you can do the following:

1) Open the command prompt and navigate to your sdk/platform-tools/ folder.

2) Type adb tcpip 5555

3) Type adb connect :5555

4) At this point you unplug your device and type adb logcat

5) At times, such as unplugging/plugging into a USB device, the logcat will become disconnected, just redo steps 3 & 4.

Comment: Is there any way I can view the logs on android itself? Also, I'm still interested in being able to send logs to my PC even if I'm not connected via USB

Comment: I added how to view the logs via WiFi. As for on the Android itself, I'm not sure.